# Blender quits automatically when rendering EEVEE animation

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm currently trying to export my animation as a PNG sequence. But everytime I hit render animation, bllender would quit automatically after rendering few images. sometimes it could be like 10 frames, but most of the time 2 frames. This is really annoying since I need to load blender again and again just to produce a few frames. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I'm using my Lenovo Ideapad 510s with AMD Radeon R7 M460 but I think Blender is using my CPU.

Comment: If you're using Eevee, Blender is rendering on your GPU (unless you explicitly set up and enabled a CPU-based OpenGL implementation). Given the R7 M460 is an entry-level GPU (with only 2GB in the Lenovo), it's likely your card is running out of memory. Try reducing the complexity of your scene and watch the memory usage while you're rendering.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely to make simpler scenes in the future.